# JavaScript "Counter" object, what is it?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, webkit

I just noticed by accident that WebKit and Firefox define a global variable called "Counter" in the window. Any idea of what this is?

On Chrome, it appears as such in the watch:

```
Counter: function Counter() { [native code] }
```

Note: this variable is not present on IE (tested with version 10)

Comment: Interesting to note is that in Chrome, `Counter` is a function, whereas in FF it appears to be an object.

Comment: Could this be a garbage collector, counting the number of references to data within the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.peschla.net/doxygen/v8_chromium_r157275/v8-counters_8h.html

I believe this is saying counters is for garbage collection, counting the number of references to any given data. Direct or Indirect to help it create a more accurate pointer for recalling that data or releasing it from cache? correct me if i am wrong, I am new..It was just more fun to google than to study.

Comment: Interesting. But why would they expose that on the page?

Comment: I suppose it could be done this way to be more efficient on their end and also couldn't you take advantage of this as a developer manipulating a browsers default garbage collection?

Comment: I'd like to know. But how? There's nothing you can seem to do with this on Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome, always used safari before. The Heap snapshot in profiles appears to be related and then at the bottom you can select one of four choices from a pull down. Dominators, containment, comparison, and summary.

Comment: The value of this is beyond me; would you agree based on the link I posted this is related to garbage collection? I only ask because Posting another Question could shed light on the value of this subject, and I think this needs a well articulated answer

Comment: I have to say this goes beyond my knowledge. Is the `Counter` variable designating this: [Counter Class Reference](http://blog.peschla.net/doxygen/v8_chromium_r157275/class_counter.html)? And does it get exposed on the page because it's public, and is in the global namespace? I'm not too sure, because there seems to be other public classes in the global namespace that appear undefined in Chrome's watch.

Comment: @Four_lo +1 all research I did also pointed to garbage collection

Comment: glad to hear it, Do you know or could you hypothesize how developers could use this to their advantage? my curiosity has been getting the best of my productivity I may the topic public before I google myself in circles some more

Answer (score 2):

The best I could find is related with Rhino:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial#Counter_example

But in webkit it fails to instanctiate:

```
var c = new Counter(7)
TypeError: Illegal constructor

var c = Counter(7)
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

In Gecko:

```
[12:33:24.608] var c = Counter(7)
[12:33:24.609] TypeError: Counter is not a function
[12:33:29.049] var c = new Counter(7)
[12:33:29.051] TypeError: Counter is not a constructor
[12:33:31.043] Counter
[12:33:31.046] [object Counter]
```

Comment: I don't think that's it though because `Counter` in FF (in the console) is an object, not a function.

Comment: @FelixKling true but can't find any other reference to it. Searching for "Javascript Counter" (and it's derivates) on google is not easy :p

Comment: Well, but then it does not really answer the question though, does it? ;)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what it's meant to do on Chrome though.