# Applying JavaScript "Counter" object

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

This question is derived from a previous question.
[JavaScript "Counter" object, what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383846/javascript-counter-object-what-is-it/15384966?noredirect=1#comment21763396_15384966)
@Gyum Fox noticed that Webkit, Firefox and Chrome define a global variable called "Counter" in the window.

After much research and little information I was lead to believe the "Counter Variable" is for garbage collection; counting the number of references to any given data and returning an accurate pointer to any objects it was still tied to. Based on this Link.

http://blog.peschla.net/doxygen/v8_chromium_r157275/v8-counters_8h.html

I am too green to fully understand. My question is, why did they choose to expose this Global "Counter" object and What benefits could this object provide over alternative methods???

Comment: No clue. But it's clearly [not intended for you to be using](https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/5157705). In chrome, it reports itself as a function, but behaves like an object (i.e. no `call` method), and it cannot be invoked. The reasons that it exists publicly may be entirely due to something internal to the JS engine that most of us really don't need to know.

Comment: If someone with a clue could take a closer look at the link I provided. It has documentation of a V8 header file and a list of various objects and or methods, which leads me to believe the object's purpose is towards a more efficient flow of information. Whether it be strictly relevant to the evolution of the browsers or if I can directly access it through my code, I feel as though any insight on the information systems we communicate with can be valuable. Like captain planet said, knowledge is power